# How to check the boolean of checkbox?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I know this might sounds duplicate questions but none of them work for me. So far that i have done is getting the value but i want to know how to get the on/off value from the checkbox. I tried hidden field but i can't get the 1/0 value from the checkbox itself. All i get is the value.

My code is like this

```
$(document).delegate('.sBorrow', 'change', function(){
            var sBorrowClass = $(this).attr('class');
            var sBorrowValue = $(this).attr('value');
            var sBorrowName = $(this).attr('name');

            if(sBorrowClass.checked = true){
                alert(sBorrowValue);
                alert("unchecked");
            }
            else{
                alert(sBorrowValue);
                alert(sBorrowClass);
            }
```

For the checkbox form is like this

```
foreach($r as $row){
            $sBorrow = $_SESSION['sBorrow'];

            echo "<tr align='center'><td>". ($startrow+1) ."</td><td>". $row['matricno'] ."</td><td>". $row['studentname'] ."</td><td>". $row['programme'] ."</td><td>". $row['title'] ."</td><td>". $row['thesis_level'] ."</td><td>". $row['serialno'] ."</td><td>". $row['bavailable'] ."</td><td>
            <form method='post'>
            <input type='checkbox' name='sBorrow' id='sBorrow' class='sBorrow' value='". $row['serialno'] ."'>
            <input type='hidden' name='sBorrow' value=0 />
            </form></td></tr>";
            $startrow++;
            //echo $row['education_level'];
```

and questions 2..
Also how to make my checkbox remains checked when the user searching for more data after check the checkbox (Livesearch Ajax). Should i use localStorage or SESSION to store the value up until the user refresh?

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator, not the comparisons which is `==` or `===`.

Comment: Oh my bad i was hoping its solve it but no. it still goes to else condition even when i checked or unchecked

Comment: Oh I didn't notice, but you are getting an attribute, not the element.

Comment: i see..mm how to get the element?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a checkbox is checked in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/how-to-check-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-jquery)

Comment: Just use `$(this)`. for example `$(this)[0].checked` or `$(this).is(":checked")` will work.

Comment: oh its work. this is what i need :) Arigato :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `attr('string')` will return the attribute value as a String which has no property `checked`. You can use `this.checked`:

```
if(this.checked) {
    //Checkbox is checked
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Yeah it does work. Thanks. Yours and Spencer Wieczorek got the credit for this.